# How to get the index of an item in a "for in" loop?

Tags: delphi, loops

The following code works, but it is not as clean/general as the `for..in` loop.

```
fInports: TArray<TMyClass>

for i:= low(fInPorts) to high(fInPorts) do begin
  Port:= fInPorts[i];
  Port.Left:= ARect.Left;  
  Port.Top:= ARect.Top + (Height div (NrInPorts+1)) * (i+1);
end; {for i}
```

The `for..in` loop is much cleaner, but does not allow me to see which item is being accessed.

```
for Port in fInPorts do begin
  Port.Left:= ARect.Left;  
  Port.Top:= ARect.Top + (Height div (NrInPorts+1)) * index;  
  //how do I get the index? -------------------------^^^^^^^
end; {for}
```

How do I know which item within the Array is currently being processed by the `for..in` loop?

Comment: Declare an integer and increment it on each iteration? Of course that goes against your desire for clean code though.

Comment: One of the reasons your first block is not "clean" is that you're mucking about with a completely frivolous and redundant check before your loop. If `fInports` is empty; i.e. `Length(fInPorts)` is 0 then: `Low(fInPorts)` is 0 and `High(fInPorts)` is -1. Therefore the loop would not iterate at all. So you can safely delete your **if** condition and the block end. This will be a huge improvement on your first option.

Comment: Does it not have to be `index + 1` in your second code block?

Comment: I would not bother with using a local `Port` variable in the first code block, just write `fInPorts[I]` twice. Since it is unavoidable to have some kind of variable in this case I would go for the normal for loop here.

Comment: Also for dynamic arrays there is no reason to use `Low()` they are always zero based anyway. I would rather use a `TObjectList<T>` here, because it is more convenient to manipulate. Unless you need to account for every CPU cycle ...

Comment: @CraigYoung, I mistakenly declared my i thus: `var i: cardinal`, causing it to not be -1, but `MaxUInt`. The `Port` variable is a mechanism to clean up the code. It also speeds things up if the compiler does not recognize that the first and subsequent references to `array[i]` refer to the same data.

Comment: @Johan Yes, using `Cardinal` is a mistake that would cause you to enter the loop when there are zero items - but not if you have range-checking enabled. Sometime back I read an article that recommended favouring the use of signed integers instead of unsigned unless there's a specific need for the semantics of unsigned. I cannot find that particular article, but did find [another](http://www.soundsoftware.ac.uk/c-pitfall-unsigned) which uses similar reasoning.

Comment: @Johan check out this solution I got. Bet you will like it. ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The whole point of a `for in` loop is that the index should not be relevant. It's the enumerator's decision which order it will return the elements in. The enumerator could change the internal order that the elements are returned and the code using it should still work. The controls could be sorted by type, name, etc. Obviously in the case of an array the compiler magic returns the elements of the array in order but with other enumerators that will not necessarily be the case.

If you want the index for your positioning, then as Jerry said, you would have to create an index and use that in your code. If it was a `TList` you could cheat and use `IndexOf` but that would be counter productive from a performance point of view.

Personally I tend to only use `for in` loops sparingly but that's just because I am old school. I am too much of a control freak.

Comment: I disagree with your statement that the index should not be relevant. If I'm enumerating through a sorted item, I expect to get the items back in that order. Given the way enumeration works, the enumerator code isn't going to be returning random elements either. Heck, in Python the only for loop IS a for...in loop! To loop a number of times there's a range function, e.g. for num in range(10). If you want the index and element, there's an enumerate function: for index, value in enumerate(some_list). Our problem is a lack of tuples although maybe generics and records could do something similar.

Comment: The `for in` loop is a bit slower but nothing that should matter except in the most critical of loops. The code is not performance critical, otherwise I would not have used the for in loop.

Comment: It is possible to write enumerators in Delphi that return index and item pairs, just like Python enumerate. But without tuples and tuple unpacking the syntax is pretty horrid. What I don't understand is why anyone feels the need to use an index at all. And I also don't agree with the suggestion that some future version of Delphi might enumerate arrays and collections in a different order. Enumeration has a well defined ordering. It is wrong to suggest otherwise.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I am not saying that the order will change in some future Delphi version. What I am saying is that the developer has the option to use a different enumerator to return them in a different order. If the index in the original list was used for positioning then that would negate the benefit of being able to change the enumerator.

Comment: I don't really understand what you are getting at then. Never mind.

Comment: @alcalde The order is determined by the enumerator. That is important. The index is not relevant. At least in the way that Delphi has implemented the feature.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot get the index when using a for in loop. Pretty much the entire point of for in loops is that they serve up items rather than indices. However, your code does not need the index at all.

```
LLeft := ARect.Left;
LTop := ARect.Top;
for Port in fInPorts do begin
  Port.Left:= LLeft;  
  Port.Top:= LTop + Height div (NrInPorts+1);
  LTop := Port.Top;
end;
```

It is true that enumerators are entitled to serve up items in any order. However, it is quite reasonable to assume that the enumerators for arrays and lists serve up the items in a specific order. That is in order of increasing index.

Answer (score -1):

IMHO you should alter your `TMyClass` class to include an `Index` property.

How to do that?

You create a global variable in the TMyClass unit and increment it on `Create()` constructor, then assign the new value to new object's Index property.

Don't forget to use a read-only published property that reads `FIndex` to avoid wrong modifications.

Before:

```
Port.Top:= ARect.Top + (Height div (NrInPorts+1)) * index;
```

After:

```
Port.Top:= ARect.Top + (Height div (NrInPorts+1)) * Port.Index;
```

Done! ;-)

Comment: Besides, if your class is used in multiple collections, the index does not makes any sense. So not a great solution. You could however add the index to the item upon adding it to the collection. Something like: `MyObject.Index:= AList.Add(MyObject);` That would work (provided the item is not added to multiple lists).

Comment: Ummm no. An item in a collection duplicating an attribute of the collection (item position) violates one of the fundamental principles of OO - encapsulation. @Johan has mentioned 1 glaring problem. But even with only 1 collection, you'd have a problem if you want to change the position of an item within the collection.

Comment: +1 for thinking out the box, -2 for duplicating data, suggesting a global variable, violating OO principles.